# c++ Operator overloading not seeing other operators

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

I have a problem. I have implemented a custom `operator*` as a member function.

In header:

```
class Matrix
{
public:
Matrix operator*(int arg); //(1)
...
}

Matrix operator*(int a, const Matrix& m)
{
    return m * a; //(2)
}
```

(1) I can do this in main.cpp:

```
Matrix a = Matrix::GetRandom.....
Matrix b = a * 2;
```

(2) On this line, I'm getting a compiler error:

> IntelliSense: no operator "*" matches these operandsnoperand types are: const Matrix * int

How do I fix it?

Comment: You could also write both operators as (non-member) friend functions `friend Matrix operator(Matrix, int);` and `friend Matrix operator(int, Matrix);`. This keeps both symmetrical and they're declared next to each other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`m` is `const`, so only `const` method can be called on it. Make `Matrix::operator*` a `const` member function:

```
Matrix operator*(int arg) const;
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `const` in your operator overload declaration:

```
Matrix operator*(int arg) const;
```